# Mysql возможность упрощения запросов

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!  Столкнулся с такой проблемой
Мне нужно подсчитать количество строк по page столбцу.
задача:

```
id|page   
1 |zlit
2 |rus
3 |rus
4 |rus
5 |zlit
```

результат:

```
total|page   
2    |zlit
3    |rus
```

Запрос такой

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(page) FROM tab WHERE page='zlit' ");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total=$myrow[0];
```

Мне для каждой страницы делать запрос или можно как-то упростить? 
заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
SELECT `page`, COUNT(*) as `total` FROM `tab` GROUP BY `page`
```